# My handy set of tabs has migrated NW (in Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I get my Error, Logcat, Debug, etc. tabs to go back to the bottom-middle of Eclipse? For some reason, they moved up between the Package Explorer and the code editor in a vertical arrangement - I really hate it when sections of an IDE break off and dock to some seemingly arbitrary area.

Comment: Drag them back to the bottom.